# « C'est » ou « ce sont » devant le pluriel

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, démonstratifs

Considérez cette phrase:

> **Ce sont les animaux** qui souffrent, pas nous quoi.

Quelle est la règle qui oblige *être* à être au pluriel ici ?

Pourquoi pas le suivant ?

> **C'est les animaux** qui souffrent, pas nous quoi.

D'après Google, on peut écrire par exemple:

> C'est les vacances.
>
> C'est les médias qui ...
>
> C'est les anglais qui ...
>
> C'est les voisins qui ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On dit les deux :

> Ce sont les animaux qui ...
>   Ce sont les voisins qui...

> C'est les animaux qui souffrent...
>   C'est les voisins qui...

L'accord au pluriel étant d'un style plus soutenu et plus employé à l'écrit qu'à l'oral.

**Références** :

- *Le bon usage* (Grevisse, 1970, dixième édition) :

> Le verbe *être* ayant pour sujet le pronom *ce* se met ordinairement au
>   pluriel quand l'attribut est un nom pluriel ou un pronom de la 3<sup>è</sup>
>   personne du pluriel. Toutefois le singulier s'emploie également, mais
>   il est plus courant dans la langue familière que dans la langue
>   littéraire.

- [La banque de dépannage linguistique](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1603).
- [Et même l’Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#19_strong-em-c-est-ce-sont-em-strong).

Comment: Je n'aurais pas pensé que "c'est + pluriel" était toléré!

Comment: @Fólkvangr    Le fait que ce soit plus soutenu que « c'est +GN pluriel » n'exclue en rien que ce soit courant. Je ne comprends pas le sens de cette remarque.

Comment: @ Je maintiens que « L'accord au pluriel est d'un style plus soutenu », et d'ailleurs la BDL (c'est toi qui y renvoie !) dit la même chose avec : « la forme plurielle est plus recherchée »?

Comment: @assylias C'est + pluriel est dans bien des cas « peu soutenu », en revanche on peut dire «c'est toi et moi», « c'est les autres », «c'est trois millions de personnes», etc.. Je ne connais pas les règles d'usage, s'il y en a.