# Singular or plural in "ce qui" construction

Tags: grammaire, pluriel

> Ce qui m'énerve en ce moment, ___ les chiens de mes voisins.

Should *c'est* or *ce sont* go into the blank? On the one hand, *les chiens* is plural so the plural form should be used. On the other hand, it is just one (group of) things, so we should use the singular.

Comment: A [very similar question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9371/cest-ou-ce-sont-devant-le-pluriel) was answered recently, the question is broader but the answer is the same.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat yes, I mentioned that other very similar question in my reply. I replied anyway to point the fact what is preceding the sentence affects the level of correctness of the singular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the pronoun ***ce*** is singular (i.e. *la chose qui m’énerve*), the singular is accepted, and likely the most common in spoken French:

> ***Ce*** qui m'énerve en ce moment, **c'est** les chiens de mes voisins.

but the plural is more stylish, especially in written French:

> *Ce qui m'énerve en ce moment, **ce sont** **les** chiens de mes voisins.*

In the pronoun is in plural (*ceux qui* = those/the ones who annoy me…), *ce sont* is mandatory:

> ***Ceux*** qui m'énerv**ent** en ce moment, **ce sont** les chiens de mes voisins.

See [« C'est » ou « ce sont » devant le pluriel](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9371/cest-ou-ce-sont-devant-le-pluriel)

Answer (score 0):

"Ce sont les chiens" is the one you have to use you not talk about the group of dogs you talk about the dogs

Answer (score 0):

The « être » verb agrees with the noun that follows:

> Ce qui m'énerve, **ce sont** les chiens des voisins.

« C’est » can be used if you phrase the sentence as:

> Ce qui m'énerve, **c'est que** les chiens des voisins aboient sans cesse.