# "ce qui sont" ou "ce qui est" devant le pluriel

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, démonstratifs

Je préfère dire ou écrire "Je vois ce qui sont des choses intéressantes" plutôt que "Je vois ce qui est des choses intéressantes". Je suis conforté dans ma préférence par des usages semblables trouvés par [Google Books](https://goo.gl/jjCCZq). (Par ailleurs, je crois qu'il ne faut pas confondre avec "pour ce qui est de", qui est invariant en nombre.)

On me dit pourtant que la première phrase n'est pas grammaticalement correcte, car l'interposition de "qui" transformerait "ce" en sujet et que "ce" est singulier.

Je connais la [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9371/cest-ou-ce-sont-devant-le-pluriel) pour c'est/ce sont. L'interposition de "qui" change-t-elle quelque chose à l'affaire?

Comment: "Ce sont des questions intéressantes". Ici, le sujet "ce" est pluriel, alors "ce" n'est pas toujours singulier. Votre première phrase est probablement grammaticalement correcte.

Comment: Le problème tiens plutôt à la totale superfluité de "ce qui" dans cette phrase. Un locuteur natif se contenterait de "Je vois des choses intéressantes" ou une variante ("Je vois là [...]", "J'y vois [...]")

Comment: @Circeus Oui, mon exemple est mauvais, mais cela ne répond pas à la question de grammaire.

Answer (score 3):

I would say both of yours alternatives are at least grammatically questionable.

Unlike *C'est* which can be and is routinely followed by a plural, *ce qui* is almost exclusively followed by a singular.

Even while rising since the nineties, *ce qui sont* occurrences are still very low (< 2%) compared to those of *ce qui est* so using the form risk being frowned upon or considered outdated.

[image: Google Ngram viewer]

Moreover, some *ce qui sont* found by google books are false positives or obvious mistakes, e.g.:

> *...plusieurs des instances formelles (DS, CPPT, **CE), qui sont** encore dénommés...*
>
> *...mettent sous pierres le corps de **ce qui sont** partis dans le monde obscur.* (should be ***ceux***)

If *ce qui* needs to be kept, I would recommend rephrasing the sentence that way:

> *Je vois **ce qui est** un ensemble de choses intéressantes.*

Comment: I totally agree. And I would say _Je vois des choses intéressantes_, or _les choses que je vois sont intéressantes_

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, the correct phrase is "*Je vois **ce que sont** des choses intéressantes*".

"*ce que*" is the subject of the verb "*sont*" and it refers to the nominal group "*des choses intéressantes*" which is on plural form. That's why the verb "*sont*" is on plural form too.

Then, I use "*que*" instead of "*qui*" because "*des choses*" are an inanimate object and "ce que sont des choses intéressantes" is the complement of direct object of the verb "*vois*".

- "**qui**" : use for animate or inanimate subject and for animate complement of direct object

for example :

"*Je vois ce qui fait un homme*" => animate complement of direct object of "*voi*s"

"*Ce qui est difficile, c'est de bien expliquer*" => inanimate subject of "*est*"

"*Qui est-ce qui est arrivé encore, c'est Marc*" => animate subject of "*est*"

- "**que**" : use for inanimate complement of direct object

for example:

"*Je vois ce que fait un homme*" => inanimate complement of direct object for "*vois*" and here I used a singular form example with "un homme" and "fait".

Comment: You are changing the meaning by replacing "qui" with "que". *Je vois ce qu'est une chose intéressante* (I understand what is meant by "an interesting thing") is very different than *je vois ce qui est une chose intéressante* (I see something that is an interesting thing).

Comment: I think that this question needs our both answers to correct grammar according to the meaning. If this is the meaning of "I see something that is an interesting thing", I translate it by : "Je vois quelque chose qui est intéressant".  Also, if I rephrase it in this meaning keeping "ce" and plural : "Ce que je vois, ce sont des choses qui sont intéressantes". We do not use "qui" for an inanimate complement of direct object. "qui" and "que" could change the meaning, that's why I used the same examples : "Je vois ce que fait un homme"/"Je vois ce qui fait un homme" to explain.