# Whether to use "c’est" or "ce sont"?

Tags: grammaire, accord

In conversation with my colleague, I said:

> C’est signe que tu es consciencieux et que tu sais faire preuve d’initiative. Et ça, c’**est** des qualités que j’apprécie.

Or should  I have said:

> [or]: Et ça, ce **sont** des qualités que j’apprécie.

I'm aware of the usual construction "ce **sont** + plural", but in this specific instance, I think I used the singular "c’est" due to the presence of the preceding "ça", which I think may tilt the scale a bit in favour of the singular "Et ça, c'est ...".

I wonder if both versions equally work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [« C'est » ou « ce sont » devant le pluriel](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9371/cest-ou-ce-sont-devant-le-pluriel)

Comment: It's a duplicate of the linked question, it's not just emphatic.

Comment: @jlliagre The question on your link deals with the *emphatic* construction "C'est X que Y", as in "Ce n'est pas en faisant ... que tu vas ...", which is not the case with my phrasing. Not to mention the presence of the preceding "ça", which I think may tilt the scale a bit in favour of the singular "Et ça, c'**est** ...". So I'm still none the wiser, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Both forms are idiomatic.

***Ce sont des*** is more used than ***c'est des***, especially in written language.

[image]

Starting the sentence with ***ça*** is shifting it toward a more informal register where the mismatch between the singular ***c'est*** and the plural ***des*** that follows is widely accepted.

[image]

The form *cela, ce sont...* sounds less acceptable than *cela, c'est* while *celles-là, ce sont...* is odd because what was just said has no gender so a neutral pronoun is expected.

If you want to avoid the issue, you can say:

> *C’est signe que tu es consciencieux et que tu sais faire preuve d’initiative. Et ce sont là des qualités que j’apprécie.*

Answer (score 2):

Orally, most people will casually say *c'est* nowadays.

But in your sentence *ce sont* is nicer, and people making a little effort to speak French a little bit better would say *ce sont* :)

Answer (score -2):

La raison pour laquelle l'emploi cité pourrait être tolérable est donné par l'Ac. Le texte ou des commentaires à l'effet de le paraphraser ne figurent pas sous la question cité en commentaires (laquelle question mène via sa réponse à la référence de l'Ac.). De plus, il n'est nullement question de cette particularité dans le texte de la question citée comme  donnant une réponse à la présente question. Il n'est pas clair, selon la compréhension que j'ai du système, s'il y a raison suffisante pour considérer la question comme résolue.

À tout hasard je répète cette avis de l'Ac. ci-dessous.

> « C’est », suivi d’un nom au pluriel ou d’un pronom autre que personnel, s’accorde avec celui-ci. Toutefois le singulier se rencontre parfois à l’écrit, particulièrement dans les cas suivants :
>
> - lorsque singulier et pluriel sont identiques pour l’oreille : Ce n’était pas des mensonges ;
> - **lorsque ce reprend un nom ou un pronom au singulier** qui le précède : Le monument qu’on aperçoit, c’est les Invalides ;

Comment: Non, clairement dans ce cas, la reference est faite a un ensemble de qualites, donc pluriel.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Il me semble que les qualités sont regroupées en un tout neutre par le pronom « ça », qui est singulier, et c'est ce mot qui compte finalement ; il n'a jamais un verbe au pluriel, c'est un pronom singulier.

Comment: Et ca, ce sont des qualites. Pour moi, il n'y a pas d'argument valable pour permettre l'utilisation du singulier car ce a quoi on se refere, c'est un semble de qualite qu'on a decrites.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher La grammaire pourrait avoir été conçue ainsi, mais ce n'est pas le cas ; on ne dit pas «De belles pages ! Ça seront des pages intéressantes pour lui. » ; on dit seulement « De belles pages ! Ça sera des pages intéressantes pour lui. » ; grammaticalement le pronom est neutre singulier. Je ne vois pas comment dans les contextes de représentation d'un ensemble on puisse le traiter tantôt  comme singulier tantôt comme pluriel ; c'est sans logique.