# Phrase avec « c’en sont » ou « c’en est »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

1- Il serait incapable de signaler les typos aux contributeurs en mathématiques car il ne saurait même pas que c’en est.

2- Il serait incapable de signaler les typos aux contributeurs en mathématiques car il ne saurait même pas que c’en sont.

À l’oreille il me semble que la deuxième proposition sonne mal, en revanche elle semble répondre au bon usage.

Il me ferait grand plaisir de lire d’autres tournures, si vous en avez à me présenter, pour autant que vous répondiez à ma question avant toute chose !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le pluriel ***c'en sont*** est extrêmement rare alors que sans le pronom, c'est le pluriel qui est la forme [la plus soutenue](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9371/cest-ou-ce-sont-devant-le-pluriel) (***ce sont***).

L'Académie française [condamne le pluriel](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#19_strong-em-c-est-ce-sont-em-strong) mais sans donner de justification.

Grevisse, sans partager cette opinion, observe que des grammairiens prônent le singulier en considérant ***c'en sont*** comme peu euphonique.

Tu prendras donc moins de risques à écrire ***c'en est*** mais rien ne t'interdit de choisir ***c'en sont*** pour plus d'originalité.

Pour ce qui est de reformulation, *typos* et *contributeurs* sont des anglicismes, je suggérerais donc :

> Il serait bien incapable de signaler les coquilles aux auteurs des articles de mathématiques, faute de savoir les identifier.

Comment: Ne faudrait-il pas reformuler la phrase? La première version sonne faux à mes oreilles; la deuxième à peine mieux. Et pourtant, en règle générale, comme vous dites, la première formule est commune, la deuxième rare.

Comment: @PatrickT Le choix entre le singulier et le pluriel est l'objet de la question, et c'était un prérequis. Je viens de proposer une reformulation.

Comment: Excellente reformulation!

Answer (score 1):

On peut dire :

- Il ne pourrait pas signaler les typos aux contributeurs en mathématiques car il serait incapable de les repérer.

Aucune des deux phrases n'est correcte car « c'en est » ou « c'en sont » signifie, après remplacement, « les typos sont des typos », ce qui ne tient pas debout.

Comment: Effectivement, la phrase en question est incohérente! Je pense que deux des idées que j’avais en tête sont entrées en interférence…Au début je voulais écrire «Il n’aurait pas été en mesure de signaler tous les typos que j’ai fait remarquer aux contributeurs en mathématiques car il n’aurait pas su que c’en était vraiment.

Comment: Mais à bien y penser je ne suis pas sûr qu’elle soit cohérente, j’ai des doutes. Quoi qu’il en soit, la tournure que tu m’as proposée est claire et rend corps à l’idée que je souhaitais exprimer, inutile donc de me torturer l’esprit davantage.